# Showing that $\mathcal{O}(X_f)\cong\mathcal{O}(X)_f$ without schemes language

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have seen this question here in the language of schemes, but I never studied this, so I hope someone can help me to solve this problem without schemes (I'm a beginner in this).

The problem is to show that $\mathcal{O}(X_f)\cong\mathcal{O}(X)_f$, where we have the following.

$\bullet \ X\subset\mathbb{A}^n_K$ is an irreducible variety over an algebraically closed field $K$

$\bullet \ \mathcal{O}(X)$ is the coordinate ring of $X$

$\bullet \ f\in\mathcal{O}(X)$

$\bullet \ X_f=\{p\in X: f(p)\neq0\}$

$\bullet \ \mathcal{O}(X_f)$ is the set of rational functions $g/h:X_f\rightarrow K$, with $g,h\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $h\neq0$ in $X_f$

$\bullet \ \mathcal{O}(X)_f = \{g/f^m\in Q(\mathcal{O}(X)): m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is the localization of $\mathcal{O}(X)$ in $f$ and $Q(\mathcal{O}(X))$ is the field of fractions of $\mathcal{O}(X)$

I started trying to show that the restriction of functions $g/f^m$ to $X_f$ would give me a map $\mathcal{O}(X)_f\rightarrow\mathcal{O}(X_f)$, which would be the isomorphism. In fact, this the only idea which looks natural to me, I can't think in anything else. But I'm having some problems to show it is injective and mostly to show it is surjective.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this proof is given in Hartshorne before he defines a scheme.  It uses just basic ideas but it's still pretty gnarly to get through it.  Do you want me to post that proof?

Comment: @Gregory Grant Yes please, I really appreciate to see the proof here.

Comment: Sure, I will post it when I get home from work, I didn't bring that book to the office today.  It will be in the next few hours sometime, depending on how things go here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the proof from Hartshorne.  I believe what you want is part (b).  It's pretty well written and followable, I was able to follow it without knowing anything about schemes.  If you want to discuss any particular points of it let me know.

[image: Hartshorne Proposition 2.2]

Comment: I had some problems at the very beginning. This is a more general setting, so it's not clear how to translate things here. I know $A=\mathcal{O}(X)$, $D(f) = X_f$ and "section" $s\in D(f)$ is just a rational function in $X_f$. What is not clear is $\mathfrak{p}$. This is a prime ideal in $A$?  Is this considerations equivalent to my initial ideas about how the isomorphism should be? Thanks.

Comment: This proof is still too general, I don't want to go too far in abstractions just to come back and prove my special case (never studied stalks or sheaf, I have no idea of what are these) . I'm pretty sure the proof of surjectivity is much more simple in the special case I'm concerned with. Is there some other text dealing with this proof? Thanks.